# Background App Refresh not updating apps

Tags: ios, multitasking

Background App Refresh won't auto update apps — why not?

<sup>iPad 2, 64 GB, iOS 7</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Background App Refresh won't update apps.

> When Background App Refresh is on, apps that take advantage of this feature can refresh themselves in the background.

<sup>Source: [Apple KB Article — iOS: Understanding multitasking](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4211)</sup>

This means that the apps can refresh their content, but Background App Refresh is not responsible for the actual updating of the binary from the App Store.

---

With regards to the actual app updating, there is a criteria which must be met before an app can be updated:

> **Intelligently scheduled updates.**
>
> iOS schedules updates during power-efficient times. Like when your device is on and connected to Wi-Fi. So your battery isn’t drained unnecessarily.

<sup>Source: Apple — iOS 7 — What's New, previously available at http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/</sup>

This means that just because the option is enabled, the update won't always take place.